# what are the hotkeys for changing the direction of extrusion in sculpting

Tags: sculpting

[image]

I have version 2.93.2 what are the hotkeys for these buttons? and how to quickly search for hotkeys in blender?

Comment: Commonly, the "opposite" in sculpting can be achieved by holding Ctrl. (Example: click and drag extrudes outwards - Ctrl + click and drag extrudes inwards)

Comment: Thank you))))))